# Google Reader replacement that does FULL history import?

Tags: google-reader

A while ago, I posted via [Google Reader alternatives: did you make a choice yet?](http://wiert.me/2013/05/22/google-reader-alternatives-did-you-make-a-choice-yet/) indicating this about Feedly:

> PRO: GR imported posts contains all history (even from blog feeds that are now defunct)

Well, I was proven wrong by this Feedly posting about the migration to their own cloud: [[IMPORTANT] Preparing to be upgraded to the new feedly cloud | Building Feedly](http://blog.feedly.com/2013/06/17/important-preparing-to-be-upgraded-to-the-new-feedly-cloud/).

> The one part we did not migrate from Google Reader is your history (too much data) so you have to expect that you are starting from a blank history and your unread counts will be reset. This is a one time issue.

Is there any Google Reader replacement that imports full history?

The reason I ask is that Google Reader has some content from a deceased friend for which there is no other way to get that content.

Comment: You can [download your Google Reader data](https://support.google.com/reader/answer/3028851). You need to do it before July 1, though, so best hurry.

Comment: @AlEverett I did that a while ago through the takeout service (see my answer how), just to make sure I got everything.

Comment: @AlEverett - the problem is that takeout doesn't allow you to download *all* of your history i.e. items not starred, shared, liked etc. You need to go through every feed and every article and star them all which is not really practical if you've subscribed to 200-300 feeds.

Comment: If you hurry, there is a service called "[Reader Is Dead](http://readerisdead.com/)" that claims to get _everything_. [Lifehacker has an article about it](http://lifehacker.com/reader-is-dead-pulls-out-all-the-google-reader-data-tha-645016987).

Comment: Too late (: The Reader API is dead, so "Reader is Dead" is dead too. Too bad: I wish I'd known this earlier (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not yet found a reader that does the full history import.

An alternative to export Google Reader through the take out link: https://www.google.com/takeout/#custom:reader

You have to start all your history first (I've done this for the blogs that are not there any more, it was a tedious process, but it works).

Now for some tool that can process the starred.json file that is inside it (:
(I know, it is something I might be able to develop myself).

*Edit:*

Some notes:

- http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/rssfeeds/google-reader-is-dead-heres-what-you-need-to-replace-google-reader/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/google-reader-data-export/
- http://htnawsaj.tumblr.com/post/47092594142/importing-google-reader-exisitng-starred-articles-to
- http://theoldreader.uservoice.com/forums/187017-feature-requests/suggestions/3748239-import-starred-json-from-google-reader-s-takeout
- http://tt-rss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1573

Comment: Just tried digg reader: it also fails to import full history.

Answer (score 1):

I had success importing my large starred.json file into Red Tree Reader and Feedbin.

Answer (score -1):

I searched for any reader which provides full history import along with all Google Reader but i found some good links you can search within.

> Link 1 :

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-more-apps-to-replace-google-reader/1918

> Link 2 (Using outlook ) :

http://howtotechguru.com/import-rss-feeds-outlook-google-reader/174

Comment: All 5 solutions in your first link are mentioned to "not import history". Your second link only imports the OPML, so that will not import history either.

Answer (score -3):

After the closure of Google Reader I first tried Fliboard, but then I realized that I do not have time to read all of my RSS subscriptions. But unsubscribe from all of them I can't, because there is important news. So I settled on two readers - Likehack.com or Summify.com

Comment: And? Do they do what is the key requirement of this question: Import Google Reader history?